# Punctuation in non-period bullets list

Tags: publishing, editing, punctuation

Desktop-publishing question: For example, in the bulleted text with non-period-at-the-end writing style, is it proper to eventually use a few sentences for one of the bullets with a period mark in-between and still do not use the period mark at the end of the last sentence? Or should it yet have a period mark as the last of these sentences may look incomplete?

I really hope my question make sense and is ok, as I'm new here.. Thanks!

UPD: Actually right now I need to decide the punctuation style in a technical doc in the Condition description column of the table. But I have the same question for the Bullets list.

Example version 1:

- A=C-B
- See Figure 1
- A=B
- See Figure 2. Actual performance is better
- A=B+C, see Figure 2

or

Example version 2:

- A=C-B
- See Figure 1.
- A=B
- See Figure 2. Actual performance is better.
- A=B+C, see Figure 2.

or

Example version 3:

- A=C-B.
- See Figure 1.
- A=B.
- See Figure 2. Actual performance is better.
- A=B+C, see Figure 2.

Comment: Hi Olenia, welcome to the site! I'm not sure I completely understand the question, do you think you could maybe provide a visual example of what you mean? i.e. a bulleted list formatted as you are describing? This question also may be a bit subjective since editors have many different punctuation styles.

Comment: Hi @Sciborg, thank you. I've updated the question. I just need to decide on a consistent style yet to make sure it is proper and readable/understandable.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now! Yes, I think this is perfectly sensible, but obviously if you are writing a scientific or technical document you should consult your particular editor or company to see what their preferred style is.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds right, but I need to suggest a valid option. I prefer Version #1 from my Examples, but is it a valid option, or formally should every complete sentence be ended with a period mark?

Comment: I would personally favor #2 for that reason, it makes more sense to my eyes to end sentences with periods and to leave mathematical expressions punctuation-less. But it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you @Sciborg! That's very helpful to get a personal opinion.

Comment: Are each "See Figure X" comments corresponding to the above equation?   As a rule, your bulleted lists should include information as similarly formatted as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 is the only consistent choice, except that the last item should have a period instead of a comma after the equation, and the "see" sentence should start with cap *S* and end with a period. Mathematical expressions do take a period according to *The Chicago Manual of Style* 12.18, which is academic style.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the comma in the last sentence. It can be broken in two sentences as you suggest, but that's entirely optional. But overall version 3, of course.

Comment: The equation is the equivalent of a sentence. The binary operation signs = and + act as verbs. "[Mathematical] Expressions must carry ending punctuation if they end a sentence" (Chicago Manual of Style 12.18; this is book publishing style). Two sentences, or independent clauses, are not joined by a comma. That would be an error called a comma splice. I don't use the word "wrong" in connection with language usage, but the comma splice is not accepted in a formal context. One could use a semicolon instead of the comma.